# Como implementar este CURL de bash en php

Tags: php, bash, script, shell

estoy probando la api de verystream con el método de subida de vídeos, pero veo que usa este curl

`curl -F file1=@/path/to/file.txt https://doge.example.com/uls/jAZUhVzeU78`

que se ejecuta desde shell.

Me preguntaba si era posible utilizar este curl en php y como seria el código, de antemano muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Para enviar un archvio con curl:

```
$request = curl_init('http://example.com/');

curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt(
    $request,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
    array(
      'file' => '@' . realpath('example.txt')
    ));

curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($request);

curl_close($request);
```

Seteando el nombre del archivo original.

```
curl_setopt(
   $request,
   CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
   array(
     'file' => '@' . realpath('example.txt') . ';filename=name.txt'
   )
);
```

Seteando el nombre orignal aplicado al envío de un archivo con formulario:

El html:  `<input type="file" name="file" />`

```
curl_setopt(
   $request,
   CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
   array(
     'file' =>
         '@'            . $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']
         . ';filename=' . $_FILES['file']['name']
   )
);
```

Seteando el tipo MIME:

```
curl_setopt(
   $request,
   CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
   array(
     'file' =>
         '@'            . $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']
         . ';filename=' . $_FILES['file']['name']
         . ';type='     . $_FILES['file']['type']
   )
);
```

Ref: http://code.iamkate.com/php/sending-files-using-curl/

Comment: No me funciona, se queda el navegador en blanco